# Pluck data from query results without making another query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Ok, I got some records from a query, something like this.

```
works = Work.do_a_long_query_with_scope(....)
```

In my controller, I want to find something else base on this works' ids, then return this works in response

```
def index
   works = Work.do_a_long_query_with_scope(....)
   not_finished_tasks = Task.find_not_finished_tasks_of_user(works.ids, current_user.id)
   # do some job with those tasks
   render json: works
end
```

This works fine except that it created 2 query , 1 with `SELECT works.id FROM works ...` for that task function, 1 with `SELECT works.* from works ...` for serializer response.

So can I use `works.ids` without making another request to DB ?

Comment: `works.pluck(:id)` will return a list of work ids.

Comment: @Emu so does `works.ids`. The problem is the JSON serialize will load all the objects but `works.ids` will also query the database to get just the `id`s. So two queries when only one is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`#load`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load) to tell the relation to load everything from the database:

```
works = Work.do_a_long_query_with_scope(....)
works.load
not_finished_tasks = Task.find_not_finished_tasks_of_user(works.ids, current_user.id)
# do some job with those tasks
render json: works
```

After `works.load`, the `works.ids` call will pull the `id`s out of the already loaded `Work`s instances rather than going back to the database.

---

Also, if your `Task.find_not_finished_tasks_of_user` call is doing something like:

```
where(id: array_of_work_ids)
```

then you could instead pass in the whole `works` relation and say:

```
where(id: works.select(:id))
```

to use a subquery instead of sending all the `id`s back to the database. The first one will do something like:

```
where id in (a_big_list_of_ids)
```

but the second will do:

```
where id in (select id from ...)
```

There may or may not be any noticeable difference depending on how big `works.ids` is. There's also a possibility that the subquery will give you different `id`s if something is changing the database between your `load` call and when the subquery executes.